# Change the list heading when move the cursor to the list element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a table of links, I want the table to be a bit fancier by changing the table heading's background color whenever I move the cursor to one of the list's links. However, I don't know how to change the attribute of the container element by affecting its smaller element. This is my code:

```
<html lang="vi">
    <head>
        <style>
.toc-container {
    max-width: 600px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background: #deff9d;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}  
.toc-container h2.index-heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 16px;
    padding-top: 16px;
}
.table-of-contents {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.table-of-contents li.author li.blog {
    background: #222;
    transition: 400ms;
    list-style: none;
}
.table-of-contents li.author{
    background-color: green;
}
.table-of-contents li.author li:nth-of-type(even).blog {
    background: #2e2e2e;
} 
.table-of-contents li.author li:hover.blog {
    background: #000;
} 
.table-of-contents li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 24px;
    padding: 16px 0;
    display: block;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="toc-container">
            <h2 class="index-heading">heading</h2>
            <ul class="table-of-contents">
                <li class="author">
                    <a href="#">Author's name</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="blog">
                            <a href="#">Nháp 1</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want when cursor move to the any li link then what should be changed ? the link should be changed to what ? please specify that

Comment: @RahulMohanty The thing that I want to change is the background color of the list's heading, the link will not change (I'll have already done its part). What I want is kinda like a hover function for the heading but instead of adding a hover to the list's heading, I want to trigger the function by move the cursor to the links in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to do this with javascript, you can use Element Event `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to achieve style change, maybe this can help you. code below

```html
  <script>
    const headerDiv = document.querySelector('.index-heading');
    const blogDiv = document.querySelector('.blog');
    blogDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
      headerDiv.style.background = 'purple'
    })
    blogDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
      headerDiv.style.background = '#deff9d'
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: tks, but somehow your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**basically your HTML code is not in a order manner so that we could not apply all the changes you need . thats why i attached the code snippet which is easily explained and you can change your design yourself as your choice . and in style , unfortunately a tag is not doing as expected but i am sure that it will work in your browser .
if any needs to be changed in my code then comment below .**

```js
let header2=document.getElementById("header2");
    let link=document.getElementById("link")
    let changeLink=()=>{
        header2.style.backgroundColor="green"
        link.style.backgroundColor="yellow"
    }
    let changeHeader=()=>{
        link.style.background="green"
        header2.style.backgroundColor="yellow"
    }
```

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#header1{
    height:85px;
}
#link{
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-top:-141px;
}
#header2{
    height:180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header1" style="background-color:red">header1</div>
<a href="https://www.blogger.com/profile/00965819760488730111">
    <div style="background-color:green" id="change">
        <div id="header2" onmouseover="changeLink()">Đặng Minh Hoàng</div>
    </div>
</a>
    <ul id="link" onmouseover="changeHeader()">
        <a href="https://cybtechnophileblog.blogspot.com/2022/10/blog-post_5.html"><div class="col my-1">Nháp1</div></a>
        <a href="https://cybtechnophileblog.blogspot.com/2022/10/blog-post.html"><div class="col my-1">Nháp2</div></a>
        <a href="https://cybtechnophileblog.blogspot.com/2022/10/nhap-3.html"><div class="col my-1">Nháp3</div></a>
        <a href="https://cybtechnophileblog.blogspot.com/2022/10/nhap-4.html"><div class="col my-1">Nháp4</div></a>
        <a href="https://cybtechnophileblog.blogspot.com/2022/10/nhap-5.html"><div class="col my-1">Nháp5</div></a>
    </ul>
</div>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: I don't think you get my question right tho :)). what I wanted was whenever I move my mouse to "nháp 1", "author's name" will change the background :)). I tried your method in my code but unfortunately, it just did not work. I really need your help so if you want more information I can send you my full code

Comment: yes , you can send me your full code

Comment: as you are saying when your cursor will move to author's name then the background should be changed . background means the author's name background or the body background ?

Comment: Cursor --> link --> change author's name background.
Cursor --> author's name --> change author's name background

Comment: this is my full code: https://github.com/Haiyahhh/Blog-index

Comment: yeah . for that your html code should be in a order manner

Comment: So what should I do? I'm so stuck

Comment: yes i have updated my answer !! please check

Comment: Is my solution right or any other changes you need .

Comment: I used a list to store the author names (since I'll add more in the future) so I think it's gonna work a little different. Can you change your code to fit in this context please?

Comment: I tried to apply your code to my code by putting everything from the author name's anchor tag to the links' unordered list into another unordered list and the author name's anchor tag is a <li> and the code stopped working. I don't know why :v

Comment: this is the edited version of your code that I created so that it fits my problem, but it doesn't work: https://github.com/Haiyahhh/Answer/tree/main

Comment: but it is working fine !!

Comment: You mean the edited version? I don't know but it doesn't work out on my computer T.T

Comment: yes the code i have edited ... it seems work fine !!

Comment: sorry i had not seen that you have edited my answer . i just run code snippet but a error is occured . ok i will try to fix it .

Comment: now please check out if there are some issues are found comment below

Comment: I coppied your code to VCS then run it on Chrome but it doesn't work at all. I don't know why the snippet work :v

Comment: but in my chrome it totally works fine .

Comment: could you please tell me what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: the color did not change that time but it works now, thanks for your helping, I really appreciate that :)

Comment: when someones answer is appropriate for your question then note that you should give a upvote to that user so that other people will find it as a useful  answer . thank you